# ReactJS: how to append a component to the App component in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to append a "Item" component which consists of some array items, in the main "App" Component. But the component is getting replaced with the new array items instead of getting appended. Following is the code snippet:

```
//the App render function
render: function() {
    return ( 
        <div> 
        {
            this.state.productDisplayed.map(function(product, i) {
                return ( 
                    <Item source = {product.url} prodId = {product.id}  key = {product.id} />
                )
            })
        }

        </div>
    )
}


//The Item render function
render: function(){
    return(
        <div className = "col-sm-4" >   
            <img src = {this.props.source} width = "70%" className = "img-responsive"></img>
            <div>{this.props.prodId} 
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

"ProductDisplayed" is an array which gets replaced by new items which are then displayed using a "for" loop.

How can i append the items as if I am adding some extra items to the main App component. I am trying to implement infinite scrolling.

Comment: this depends vastly on the code that actually "appends" (replace, in your present case) items data to the productDisplayed state. but yeah, the principle evoked in either answer will do what you need. the rendering is dependant on the state. append items to the state instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to append items to your app component, you need to append data to your `productDisplayed` state array

For this you can do something like

```
addItem=(item)=>{
     var productDisplayed=[...this.state.productDisplayed];
     productDisplayed.push(item);
     this.setState({productDisplayed});
}
```

And you can call this function `addItem` on some event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append them to the array in your state.  I have used the function argument to setState because your nextState is dependent on your previous state.

```
component ProductList extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.setState({
            productDisplayed: []
        });
    }

    getMoreItems = ( startingId ) => {
        Api.getMoreItems(startingId).then(this.addItems);
    }

    addItems = ( items ) => {
        this.setState(( prevState ) => ({
          updatedItems: [...prevState.productDisplayed, ...items]
        }));
    }

    render() {
        // no changes
        // something triggers this.getMoreItems(id)
    }
}
```